# Sync sqlite database to MYSQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, sqlite

... hello, world 
I’m trying to sync my offline database which is Sqlite to my remote web server which has Mysql database. 
I tried to extract data from sqlite to xml and sync xml with mysql database but no success.
Any ideas how to do this?
Thanks in advance
Off course I’m using wpf c#

Comment: Look at [Microsoft Sync Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt490616.aspx)

Comment: @BWA, nope, sync framework won't work since it's not SQL Server and moreover you can't sync cross party databases like that

Comment: @Rahul thanks, I didn't use it, I thinki it's more elastic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't sync like that from cross party databases. What you will have to do is import your SQLite database to MySQL and then can set up `REPLICATION` probably .. just an idea, depends on what's your end goal is

Comment: What if i used sql server as my online database?

Comment: My goal is to be able to sync the online database to an android app

Comment: So all data will be updated on both sides (desktop software & android app)

Comment: @Warlock, if it's SQL server then you can use `MS sync Framework` as commented by other user